# Missing characters in custom Typeface on android

Tags: android, character, typeface

I'm using SegoeWP typeface in my android project. 
Some chars (kazakh) are missing and displays like squares. If I disable this typeface and use default characters displays well. But this doesn't occur in same project with same typeface in ios project.

Comment: Get unicode of that character and then try to print on android device, see its supporting or not?

Comment: Same result. But if I try to print it with unicode code of character or just character without using typeface it prints well. Why on iOS with same typeface all is working well?

Comment: Ya, because its depends on hardware also. Ios device hardware supporting that font, and same on android doesn't. For supporting this you need to make changes at framework level, adding font in android sdk.